# How to in RTSP protocol TEARDOWN only one track?

Tags: streaming, rtsp

I do:
`PLAY rtsp://addr/track1`
I get ok response and I send another one but for `track2`. One is for audio and another one is for video, question is: How can I TEARDOWN only one of them only? let's say: `TEARDOWN rtsp://addr/track1`. Is this even possible or should I just `TEARDOWN rtsp://addr/` and play again only one track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the RTSP specification definitely allows this but in the end I guess this depends on server implementation/support. Easiest thing would be to write a quick script to test if your server supports it.

The "[Media on Demand (Unicast)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326#page-63)" example section shows such a scenario.

Comment: ok thanks, I thought so, I just wasn't sure and I tested it but when I close one track second one is closing also so maybe this is server implementation like this, thanks again